# How to use bootstrap grid system without write regular class for ex : class-md-8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, grid

Woocommerce plugin which is for WordPress conflict with bootstrap grid system because they use same column classes.

So, to fix this conflict, I must use the bootstrap column system without regular class names.

For example, I must write different thing from this: `class="col-md-8"`

What can I write to use the bootstrap grid system instead of `col-md-8`?

Also, this problem shows that big projects need a prefix.

Bootstrap must use a prefix like `b-col-md-8` also it requires for woocommerce.

Comment: Why are using two grid-layout systems? Do use a CSS preprocessor  ?

Comment: @mahan My website design based on bootstrap grid system because its so popular also easy usage.The other grid system comes from a wordpress plugin, I dont want use it but it is default so I cant change it.